# Change audio speed using ffmpeg node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, ffmpeg

how do i change the speed of the song output using this function:

```
function addAudio()
{
      console.log("adding audio...");

      ffmpeg()
      .videoCodec('libx264')
      .format('mp4')
      .outputFormat('mp4')
      .input(song)
      .input(video)
      .output(output1)
      .on('end', () => {                    
          resolve(output1);
      }).on('error', (_err) => {
          reject(_err);
      }).run();
}
```

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

this shows command line input but not sure how to use it in js function?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```js
ffmpeg("./audio.mp3").audioFilter("atempo=2.0").output("./fasterAudio.mp3").run();
```

Keep in mind that this is only .mp3 files and isn't a .mp4 or .mkv file.